# Perl, Reading a single variable from multiple files

Tags: perl, file, search, variables, config

I have to grab a configuration directive from multiple configuration files for a series of identical web applications, each in their own folders.

I have the code to step through and open each file, in it's own folder. what I am lacking is a statement that will return the value specified in the config:

```
$variable="value"
```

I want to search for `$variable`, and return with `"value"` , perform my operation with that value, and close the file.

I know it's got to be something simple I am forgetting. Anyone have some hints?

Comment: This is relatively simple.  What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use several of the existing config modules from CPAN (Searching for [Config](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Config) for example)

There are modules for almost all flavours and needs of config files: (Examples)

- [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/~tlinden/Config-General-2.50/General.pm)
- [Config::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Config-Auto-0.38/lib/Config/Auto.pm)
- [Config::INIPlus](http://search.cpan.org/~kilna/Config-INIPlus-1.0.0/lib/Config/INIPlus.pm)
- [Config::YAML](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Config-YAML-1.42/lib/Config/YAML.pm)

Don't reinvent the wheel by coding another configuration module.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Config::Model](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config%3a%3aModel) , comes with cli and gui editors

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
ls webapps/*/conf/*.conf | xargs perl -nle 'print "$ARGV: $1" if /\$variable\s+=\s+"([^"]+)"/'
```